# How to compare IEnumerable<string> for null in Linq query

Tags: linq

For the following query:

```
 var result = from sch in schemeDashboard
         join exp in Expenditure on sch.schemeId equals exp.SchemeCode
         into SchExpGroup
         where sch.SectorDepartmentId == selectedDepartmentId &&
               sch.YearCode == StateManager.CurrentYear
         orderby sch.ADPId
         select new
         {
            ModifiedAmounts = SchExpGroup.Select(a => a.ModifiedAmounts),
            ProjectName = sch.schemeName,
            ADPNo = sch.ADPId,
            Allocation = sch.CurrentAllocation,
            Expenditures = from expend in SchExpGroup
                           where expend.YearCode == StateManager.CurrentYear && 
                                 expend.DepartmentId == selectedDepartmentId &&
                                 InvStatus.Contains(expend.Status)
                         orderby expend.ADPId
                         group expend by expend.InvoiceId
          };
```

I want to filter the above query on a condition so that result gives only those records where "ModifiedAmounts" are not null. I have tried as follow:

```
 if (rbList2.SelectedIndex == 6)
{
 result = result.Where(a => a.ModifiedAmounts != null));
}
```

but this gives error as:

> Cannot compare elements of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1'. Only primitive types,
>   enumeration types and entity types are supported.

Any suggestions as I am lost as how to rephrase the filtered query.

Comment: I think a problem is that ModifiedAmounts will anyway never be null but rather an empty list. Unless SchExpGroup is null in which case the expression will fail on a null ref.Maybe try result = result.Where(a => a.ModifiedAmounts.Any()));

Comment: @Reasurria That looks like an answer to me :)

Comment: @DavidG Thanks David. Made an answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that ModifiedAmounts will never be null. Select will return an empty list. Unless SchExpGroup is null in which case you will get a null reference exception.

Try changing your code to

```
result = result.Where(a => a.ModifiedAmounts.Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (rbList2.SelectedIndex == 6)
{
 result = result.Where(a => a.!ModifiedAmounts.Any());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)